# How to get row details by clicked button placed in column?

Tags: button, extjs, grid

I have started to use ExtJs 4. I have grid with buttons in one column. I can't manage to get button click for button in selected cell by controller. I would like to get click and then details for row in order to open extra window with details.

Code:

```
Ext.define('AP.controller.List', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores : ['Users'],
    models : ['User'],
    views : [ 'List', 'Details' ],

    init : function() {
        console.log("users");
        this.control({
            'viewport > listPanel > userlist' : { 
                itemdblclick : this.userDbCClicked
            },
            'viewport > listPanel button AND WHAT MORE ?' : {
                click : this.statusButtonClicked
            }       
        });
    },

    userDbCClicked : function(grid, record) {
        console.log("user db clicked");

    },


    statusButtonClicked : function(grid, record) {
          // Here I would like to get row details after click on button in column
        console.log("statusButtonClicked clicked ");
    }

});
```

What should be put instead this code:

```
        'viewport > listPanel button AND WHAT MORE?' : {
            click : this.statusButtonClicked
        }
```

Of course it dosen't work. How to get row by click on button in cell ?

Thanks in advance for help.

ExtJs is very powerfull framework but first steps are realy difficulted sometimes.

Bogus

Answer (score 0):

put an action:'statusbutton' in your button config

then use 'viewport > listPanel > button[action=statusbutton]'

Answer (score 0):

What Chris says is true. You can also you a name property on your button, it's just a way of querying your components. Explained here:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

{
    xtype: 'button',
    name: 'statusbutton'
}

'viewport > listPanel > button[name=statusbutton]'

Here is a good starting guide for Ext.Apps:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt1
and another one:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture